# Javascript / Neo4j - Store GeoJSON Object as Node Property

Tags: javascript, neo4j, geojson

I am attempting to store a GeoJSON object as a property of a node in a Neo4j database with the following cypher statement where `boundary.boundary` is a FeatureCollection and `boundary.centroid` is a Point:

```
UNWIND $fieldsToCreate AS obj

MERGE (f:Field {
  id: apoc.create.uuid(),
  xId: obj.fieldXId,
  legacyId: obj.legacyId,
  name: obj.name
})

FOREACH (boundary IN obj.boundary |
  CREATE (b:Boundary) SET
    b.id = apoc.create.uuid(),
    b.boundary = boundary.boundary,
    b.centroid = boundary.centroid,
    b.name = boundary.name
  MERGE (f)-[:HAS_BOUNDARY { from: datetime() }]->(b)
)

RETURN f AS field
```

The following error is returned:

`Neo4jError: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof`

What is the proper way to store GeoJSON to a Neo4j database?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've gotten an answer to this question, but it's possible, depending on how you're ingesting the data, to set the GEOJSON as a string and then transform it when you query the node.

Comment: This is exactly how I ended up implementing and it has worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up storing the GEOJSON as a string and transforming when querying. There has been little downside to this pattern for my use case.